# Animating Card components in my slider in react app not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a slider in my react app that slides my card components when any of the icon buttons are clicked. When clicked I want each card to show the fade animation but it only works when the page reloads. I am using css animation. I am using the following code

```js
 <div className={classes.root}>
      <div className={classes.slider}>
        <Card image={carddata[slider].image} slider />
      </div>

      <ArrowBackIosIcon
        fontSize="large"
        style={{ left: 0 }}
        className={classes.arrow}
        onClick={prevSlide}
      />
      <ArrowForwardIosIcon
        fontSize="large"
        style={{ right: 0 }}
        className={classes.arrow}
        onClick={nextSlide}
      />
    </div>
```

The CSS class is following

```
 slider: {
    animation: 'fadeeffect 3000ms linear 250ms',
  },

 @keyframes fadeeffect: {
    "0%": {
      opacity: 0,
    },
    "25%": {
      opacity: 0.25,
    },
    "50%": {
      opacity: 0.5,
    },
    "100%": {
      opacity: 1,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add *slider* class when you want to show the image, but you are adding it on the load e.g on click. I have provided a sandbox example to show you how to do it:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
const myRef = useRef(null);

const handleClick = ()=>{
myRef.current.classList.add('slider');
}

 <div className={classes.root}>

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Show The Element</button>

      <div /*className={classes.slider}*/ ref={myRef} >
        <Card image={carddata[slider].image} slider />
      </div>

      <ArrowBackIosIcon
        fontSize="large"
        style={{ left: 0 }}
        className={classes.arrow}
        onClick={prevSlide}
      />
      <ArrowForwardIosIcon
        fontSize="large"
        style={{ right: 0 }}
        className={classes.arrow}
        onClick={nextSlide}
      />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so this works only the first object from the carddata.  I need the animation to work on all 3 objects. I think once we add the class we need to remove it as well.

Comment: @AliRaza Yest you have to remove it when you click on that button again. I just wanted to show you that you have to add the class on demand not on start. for other cards you can add 2 other refs. or you can make the cards component and set that class inside the card.